# SSL socket in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, ssl

I need to communicate with a device that uses SSL. It used to use socket to communicate with my Delphi app, but now I'd like to use security communication with the device.

So, is there a TServerSocket and TClientSocket equivalent component that I can use SSL?

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in direct equivalent in Delphi. You can use Indy with either OpenSSL or [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-ssl.php) SSL classes however Indy is not a drop-in replacement for TServerSocket/TClientSocket, as they use very different coding models. Or you can use TElSecureClientSocket and TElSecureServerSocket classes of SecureBlackbox - they are descendants and direct replacements for TClientSocket and TServerSocket respectively. Note: SecureBlackbox is our product.

Comment: Saying that "Indy is not compatible with TServerSocket/TClientSocket" is a bit misleading. A `TClientSocket` can communicate with a `TIdTCPServer`, and a `TServerSocket` can communicate with a `TIdTCPClient`, just fine. TCP is TCP regardless of what wrapper is being used on each end. To use SSL with `TServerSocket`/`TClientSocket`, you have to hook them up to the OpenSSL or Crypto/STunnel APIs manually, that's all. Indy wraps the OpenSSL API natively, but its SSL architecture is abstracted so third-party SSL implementations (like SecureBlackBox) can be used.

Comment: @Remy would a "not a drop-in replacement" sound better? I had hard time trying to guess the right word, so I'll update an answer if this one sounds better or if you have a better suggestion for that word.

Answer (score 3):

[ICS from François Piette](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html) is a excellent open source library with SSL support.